# https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin gives a 404

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

Where is the sonar-css-plugin gone ?

I was trying to install a sonarqube test instance but couldn't install this plugin, as the github repository seems gone.

Comment: https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-css - that was all I found

Comment: Yeah, but this is the old repo as it says the new one is here https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to stop contributing to the SonarQube ecosystem.

Tamas Kende is (re)taking the lead on the CSS / SCSS / Less plugin that is now hosted at https://github.com/kalidasya/sonar-css-plugin

Comment: What will be the new licence, if I may ask ?

Comment: That's a half true. You have back to the game and [the link](https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin) is alive again ;)

Answer (score 1):

This plugin has been removed by the author

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it has been removed, but you can still download the plugin from official Maven repository:

- http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.css%22%20AND%20a%3A%22sonar-css-plugin%22
- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/css/sonar-css-plugin/